# Prove: $ (A \times C) \setminus (B \times C) = (A \setminus B) \times C $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove: $ (A \times C) \setminus (B \times C) = (A \setminus B) \times C $

So, what I have done so far is:

$(x,y) \in (A \times C) \setminus (B \times C) \Rightarrow \\ 
(x,y) \in (A \times C) \space and \space(x,y) \notin (B \times C) \Rightarrow \\
(x \in A \space and  \space y\in C) \space and \space (x\notin B \space or \space y\notin C) \Rightarrow
$

and I'm not sure what to do next in order to get $(A \setminus B) \times C$ because I assume that I need something like: $ (x\in A \space and \space x\notin B) \space and \space y\in C$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You get $x\in A$ and $y \in C$ and $x \notin B$ because you cannot have $y \in C$ and $y \notin C$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x\in A \land y\in C) \land (x\notin B \lor y\notin C)$$
Regroup the terms between $\land$:
$$\iff x\in A \land (y\in C\land (x\notin B \lor y\notin C))$$
Apply the distributive law:
$$\iff x\in A \land((y\in C\land x\notin B )\lor (y\in C\land y\notin C))$$
$y\in C\land y\notin C$ is false and can be pruned:
$$\iff x\in A \land y\in C\land x\notin B$$
$$\iff x\in (A-B)\land y\in C\iff(x,y)\in(A-B)×C$$